# renderProps undefined in Server side/Isomorphic Rendering for React/React-Router + Node/Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to get server side/Isomorphic rendering working for a react application in concert with react-router.

My `route.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

import Test from './components/test';

export default (
  <Route path="/test" component={ Test }>
  </Route>
);
```

My `server.js`:

```
'use strict';

require('babel-core/register')

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var compression = require('compression');
var http = require('http');

var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router = require('react-router');
var match = Router.match;
var RoutingContext = Router.RoutingContext;
var routes = require('./src/routes');


var app = express();
var server;
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(compression());

// Set path to public assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {

  console.log('URL: ', req.url);
  console.log('Routes: ', routes);

  match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    console.log('Render Props: ', renderProps)
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      res.status(200).send(ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps)))
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
})

server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

So when I run npm run start it simply calls `node` on `server.js`. The server starts properly but all requests, including the `/test` come back as 404s.

I console.log'd the req.url, and it is returning the proper url. I did the same for the "routes" file and it is definitely finding the correct file. Here is the output from those logs:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
URL:  /test
Routes:  { default:
   { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
     type:
      { [Function]
        displayName: 'Route',
        createRouteFromReactElement: [Function: createRouteFromReactElement],
        propTypes: [Object] },
     key: null,
     ref: null,
     props: { path: '/test', component: [Object] },
     _owner: null,
     _store: {} } }
Render Props:  undefined
GET /test 404 19.596 ms - 9
```

However the `renderProps` is always undefined and the response returns 404. I thought I followed the examples properly but I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after a long debug i found some things that could 
fixed this issues, below are few points that i had change in my 
application :-

i) First of all your test component should return a proper dom element that react can render instead of only just rendering the component. You should return either null or a proper container element containing as many elements you need.Please see the example below.(This was the first mistake i was doing in my application.)

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { super(props); }

    render () {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>opopooopppopo</h1>
                        <p>This is your world.</p>
                    </div>
                );
    }
}
```

ii) Use **RouterContext** instead of **RoutingContext** in your code base this worked for me, this was major issue in my code. Because **RoutingContext** has been **deprecated** in new version of react-router. This change fixed my issue.

```
res.status('200').send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>));
```

**(Note : Please don't forget to import RouterContext from react-router module.)**

**//Import statement for router context from react-router**

```
var RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
```

iii) If none of the above things works then change the match function use **routes.default** instead of only **routes**. **Change: match({routes : routes, location} to match({routes : routes.default, location}**, This change is necessary if you are using babel 6. Try this with combination of RoutingContext and RouterContext since i don't know which version of react-router and babel are you using. So the combination are :-

a) match({ routes : **routes** }) with combination of res.status('200').send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<**RoutingContext** {...renderProps}/>));

b) match({ routes : **routes** }) with combination of res.status('200').send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<**RouterContext** {...renderProps}/>));

c) match({ routes : **routes.default** }) with combination of res.status('200').send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<**RoutingContext** {...renderProps}/>));

d) match({ routes : **routes.default** }) with combination of res.status('200').send(ReactDOM.renderToString(<**RouterContext** {...renderProps}/>));